# Mac and Windows difference header path (/ vs \)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unix, directory-structure, windows

I have a Windows project that also works on XCode. But I had to changed all the source header paths like

```
#include "Adapter\EngineAdapterFactory.hpp"
```

to

```
#include "Adapter/EngineAdapterFactory.hpp"
```

This is quite annoying and I might have to reverse the process for Visual Studio later. How can others solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should be able to use `Adapter/EngineAdapterFactory.hpp` on both platforms.**

(At least that's the case with GCC on Windows.)

*Actually, that's not just the trait of compilers - even with Windows Explorer you should be able to navigate with `/` as directory separator. Open up Explorer and insert in your address bar something like: `c:/Some/Folder/Structure`. Should work flawlessly unless you're on a really old Windows version (I can confirm it working on XP and up, but probably it's there even longer). Thanks, Microsoft, for being compatible! :)*

Answer (score 4):

You should *never* use `\` in a include path, and its not a matter of platform but language (6.4.7/3 from the C99 standard) :

> If the characters `'`, `\`, `"`, `//`, or `/*`
>   occur in the sequence between the `<`
>   and `>` delimiters, the behavior is
>   undefined. Similarly, if the
>   characters `'`, `\`, `//`, or `/*` occur in
>   the sequence between the `"` delimiters,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Although some compilers *may* accept `\` in an include path, they are all *required* to accept `/`.